# '!Unknown version!' error

Tags: antlr

I'm using an ANTLR grammar with Python. It used to work fine, but now I'm getting the following error when I import the lexer:

> ValueError: Bad version string '!Unknown version!'

I can trace this back to the antlr3 executable:

> $ antlr3 -version
>   ANTLR Parser Generator  Version !Unknown version!

The generated parser and lexer seem fine, except for the version string. I am using the antlr3 provided by Ubuntu's repositories (12.04).  I guess I could install ANTLR by hand, but I think this should work out of the box - maybe I've misconfigured something somewhere?. Is there a known trick I am missing, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying to do the same, and concluded that the current `antlr3` package in Ubuntu's repositories doesn't work properly with the Python runtime support. The other Ubuntu package `python-antlr` is even more obsolete as it's supposed to work with ANTLR 2. I suggest that you uninstall `antlr3` and install ANTLR by hand together with the right Python runtime support.

Since I've just been through this myself, and found that the instructions are a bit scattered around, here's a summary of how to do it.

1. Uninstall the antlr3 package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge antlr3
   ```
2. Get the complete Java binaries for the latest ANTLR 3.x:

   ```
   wget http://www.antlr3.org/download/antlr-3.5.tar.gz
   ```
3. Prepare to install the Python runtime:

   ```
   tar xzf antlr-3.5.tar.gz
   cd antlr3-antlr-3.5/runtime/Python
   ```
4. Before you can call the install script, you have to patch the version number to point to what's available online. You can do this by editing `ez_setup.py` and changing `DEFAULT_VERSION = "0.6c5"` into `DEFAULT_VERSION = "0.6c11"`.
5. Now you should be able to install the Python runtime with:

   ```
   sudo python setup.py install
   ```

   To see if it works, try `import antlr3` into a Python shell. You shouldn't get any error.
6. Now, you have to install the corresponding version of ANTLR proper, which is in Java. For this, make sure you have a JVM installed (e.g., `sudo apt-get install default-jdk`).
7. Get the latest ANTLR 3 jar:

   ```
   wget http://www.antlr3.org/download/antlr-3.5-complete.jar
   ```
8. Permanently add the jar to your classpath (of course, you may move it where you want and adjust the path accordingly):

   ```
   echo 'export CLASSPATH=~/antlr-3.5-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH' >> ~/.bashrc
   ```
9. Optional, but recommended: add a shell alias to call ANTLR 3:

   ```
   echo "alias antlr3='java -jar ~/antlr-3.5-complete.jar'" >> ~/.bashrc
   ```

That's it! After you reread your .bashrc, see if everything works with `antlr3 -version`. You should get a message such as:

```
ANTLR Parser Generator  Version 3.5
```